# JPEG streaming (live555)

Tags: c++, streaming, jpeg, live555

Can anyone help with streaming JPEG/JPG files via live555 and play it on vlc.
I think I have a problem in this part:

```
ServerMediaSession* sms = ServerMediaSession::createNew(*env, "testStream", inputFileName,"Session streamed by \"testJPEGVideoStreamer\"",
                       True /*SSM*/);

sms->addSubsession(....?????....Subsession::createNew(*videoSink, rtcp));
rtspServer->addServerMediaSession(sms);
```

I do not know which subsession file I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

try a `PassiveServerMediaSubsession` - this is what the test programs use.